# I have a problem printing within a foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

[image: this is my table on database]

```
<?php
require '../koneksi.php';

$kategori=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM kategori");

?>
```

```
<li class="mb-3">
            <div class="col-12">
            <label for="kategori" class="form-label">Kategori surat</label>
            <select class="form-select" name="kategori" id="kategori" required>
                <option value="" selected="">Pilih kategori surat</option>
                <?php
                    foreach ($kategori as $key => $value) {                 
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>"><?php echo $value['kategori']; ?></option>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../JQuerydashboard.js"></script>
            </div> <!-- akhir dari kategori -->
        </li>
```

i have database with table name is "kategori". "kategori" have id from 1-5. i want to print that id from 1-3. how to do it?

Comment: Looks like the question is about PHP, not JavaScript. Also, how do you fetch the data from the database?

Comment: So the issue isn't really about printing, but rather how to only print some of the records? Wouldn't it be easier to only fetch the ones you want to use from the database?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM kategori ORDER BY ID LIMIT 3`

Comment: @Phil thanks you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<li class="mb-3">
            <div class="col-12">
            <label for="kategori" class="form-label">Kategori surat</label>
            <select class="form-select" name="kategori" id="kategori" required>
                <option value="" selected="">Pilih kategori surat</option>
                <?php
                    $counter = 0; 
                    foreach ($kategori as $key => $value) { 
                    if($counter > 3){
                       break;
                    }
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>"><?php echo $value['kategori']; ?></option>
                <?php
                    $counter++;
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../JQuerydashboard.js"></script>
            </div> <!-- akhir dari kategori -->
        </li>
```

Just have to create a counter, and everytime the counter increments it will represent an id and if it is bigger than 3 you just end the foreach loop.

Comment: thanks this answer help me

Comment: The query doesn't use `ORDER BY`, which means the order of the results is not guaranteed. Just counting the echoed results would thus not mean that results of ID 1-3 have been echoed.

Comment: Not limiting the result set makes the query highly inefficient, which could have been pointed out.